# Replace lock screen in android

Tags: android, locking

How to customize android lock screen with the same
Here i am given a image what i want in this question.

[image]

If anyone know about any clue then please give me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A simple unlock like that could be done by just toggling imageviews or imagebuttons (I am assuming you need to press on each fox and the fox then disappears).  When all foxes have been pressed, you unlock the app.

Comment: Thanks for given answer, You got my point what i want, i want to customize lock screen i have done lot of r&d over it buy don't get any clue if you have please share with me .

Comment: You cannot customise the current lockscreen (unless you rebuild the source code of course) but you can implement your own lock screen on your own app in the way I described above.